# List comprehension specifying the position of element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Here is a list

```
l = ['Bear', 'Apple', 'Bread', 'Apes', 'Bones', 'Axes']
```

I want to sort this list through list comprehension. Putting words starting with 'A' in front and with 'B' at the end. I want the code to be in the fashion below -

```
l = [putfirst(i) if i.startswith('A') else putlast(i) else for i in l]
```

After doing this I want it to be like

```
l = ['Apple','Apes','Axes','Bear','Bread','Bones']
```

Comment: What do you mean _"preserve the order of the list"_? The order of the original list `l` _is_ preserved. `sorted()` returns a _**new**_ list, so `l` is unaffected. The `sort` method of list however, _does_ change the list.

Comment: You **do** want to sort. Sorting is altering the order based on certain rules. You are sorting on the first letter *only*.

Comment: You mean you don't want to alphabetize the list of words.  @Martin Pieters answer does what you want with Python's sorting functions, where you can specify the type of sorting you'd like.

Comment: If it's all about `A`'s and `B`'s then you could you filter them out and join: `[x for x in l if x.startswith('A')] + [x for x in l if not x.startswith('A')]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I know the other methods. I specifically wanted to know if there is possibility in list comprehension to put elements at specific place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can i reframe the question again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehensions process things in the same order your input iterable produces them. They *can't be used to re-order the entries*.

Use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) instead:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda word: word[0])
l.sort(key=lambda word: word[0])
```

`sorted()` produces a new list, `list.sort()` sorts an existing list in-place.

The `key` callable here tells `sorted()` to only use the first letter when deciding to sort. Words with the same starting letter are left in the same relative order:

```
>>> l = ['Bear', 'Apple', 'Bread', 'Apes', 'Bones', 'Axes']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda word: word[0])
['Apple', 'Apes', 'Axes', 'Bear', 'Bread', 'Bones']
```

Comment: Thanks ! I couldn't phrase the question correctly. But got the answer from your first line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sorted()` function:

```
l = ['Bear','Apple','Bread','Apes','Bones','Axes']

new_l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
['Apple', 'Apes', 'Axes', 'Bear', 'Bread', 'Bones']
```